# Is there a law in India that determines the punishment on the basis of quantity of narcotic drugs possessed by a person?

Tags: criminal-law, india, indian-constitutional-law, indian-penal-code, drugs

Suppose a person was found with 1kg of a narcotic drugs and another person with say 1000kgs does the punishment for the crime differ for both the people accused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a law in India that determines the punishment on the basis of quantity of narcotic drugs possessed by a person?**

**Yes**

The Indian Narcotic Drugs and Psychotropic Substances Act 1985 provides a sliding scale for various quantities but as you do not specific which drug(s) are involved,  let's use prepared opium as an example at [s.17 of that Act:](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_2_2_00029_198561_1517807326222&sectionId=25119&sectionno=17&orderno=21)

> 17. Punishment for contravention in relation to prepared opium. -
>
> Whoever, in contravention of any provision of this Act or any rule or order made or condition of licence granted thereunder, manufactures, **possesses**, sells, purchases, transports, imports inter-State, exports inter-State or uses prepared opium shall be punishable,--
>
> - (a) where the contravention involves **small quantity, with rigorous imprisonment for a term which may extend to one year**, or with fine which may extend to ten thousand rupees, or with both; or
> - (b) where the contravention involves **quantity lesser than commercial quantity but greater than small quantity, with rigorous imprisonment for a term which may extend to ten years**, and with fine which may extend to one lakh rupees; or
> - (c) where the contravention involves **commercial quantity, with rigorous imprisonment for a term which shall not be less than ten years but which may extend to twenty years**, and shall also be liable to fine which shall not be less than one lakh rupees but which may extend to two lakh rupees:
>
> Provided that the court may, for reasons to be recorded in the judgment, impose a fine exceeding two lakh rupees.

Whether the quantities are determined by the court to be *small*, *lesser than commercial*, or *commercial* will depend on the evidence such as previous convictions, trafficking paraphernalia, the defendant's drug usage etc, as well as the actual weight.